# Problems in Installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, iso

How do I open an `.iso` file (Firefox won't work)?

Why isn't what I downloaded to install Ubuntu an executable file?

Comment: An ISO is a sort of a CD but as a file ([see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image)). You can write an ISO to a CD and this one can be written to a CD or USB flash to create a Live disk to install or try Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you on windows or ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Burn your ISO file to the Media such as DVD or CD and Boot it to get install, you can't Open the ISO file using Firefox, Burn it using some software's such as Nero in Windows Machine, Use k3b in Linux to Burn the ISO file to CD or DVD

Answer (score 1):

You can open .iso files in nautilus in easy way just navigate to the `*.iso` file , then  `Right click -> Open with Archive Mounter`.

Or you can install the Furius ISO mount application

```
sudo apt-get install furiusisomount
```

Comment: I think that this will not help the OP that asked "… to install Ubuntu". He or she is clearly expecting the classical .exe or .MSI installer of Windows...

Comment: nope the second part is another question

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively there's 2 ways to install an ISO, Flash Drive or DVD. if you i have a 2GB flash disk, then try these

- launch **startup disk creator** application from Ubuntu
- select the ISO file from the top parameter
- select the flash drive from the second parameter (ONLY AFTER BACKING UP YOUR DATA)
- Erase the disk and then make startup disk
- then reboot with flash drive as an option from BIOS

or you can just right click on the ISO file and select **Write to Disk** option after you have inserted your CD/DVD and once it's detected the media, you can click on **Create Image**

Here's a screen shot of how the application looks like
[image]

**NB: IT ONLY WORKS FOR UBUNTU RELATED ISO'S**

Comment: He has no Ubuntu, only ISO, so it would be better to use Universal USB Installer from Windows.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know that. try [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) on Windows or MAC

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is not a program, is an operating system.

You are advised to

a) backup your data before trying to install it and

b) read ALL of http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support and be sure to understand it before starting.